# How to post ajax data to controller without onChange element with Yii?

Tags: php, ajax, yii

When i write ACC_CODE, ACC_UMUM get data from controller, and ACC_LEVL is get data from controller on value ACC_UMUM. But It's must use 'tab' on keyboard for change cursor and edit entry again then sending data to controller. How to sent automatically, data from ACC_UMUM to controller if data isset or empty, before submit form?

```
<?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'ACC_CODE',array('span'=>10,'maxlength'=>20,'autocomplete'=>'off','help'=>'Batas Kode 20 karakter',
        'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('OpenReadOnlySatu'),
                'data'=>array('code_acc'=>'js:this.value'),
                'success'=>'js:function(data) { $("#Accoumdb_ACC_UMUM").val(data); }',
        )
    )); 
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'ACC_UMUM',array('id'=>CHtml::activeId($model,'ACC_UMUM'),'span'=>10,'maxlength'=>20,'autocomplete'=>'off',
        'ajax' => array(
                'type'=>'POST',
                'url'=>CController::createUrl('OpenReadOnlyDua'),
                'data'=>array('umum_acc'=>'js:this.value'),
                'success'=>'js:function(data) { $("#Accoumdb_ACC_LEVL").val(data); }',
        )
    )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'ACC_LEVL',array('id'=>CHtml::activeId($model,'ACC_LEVL'), 'span'=>3,'maxlength'=>1,'autocomplete'=>'off')); ?>
```

Comment: u can got data based on UMUM  from server when u load if... it is set... and apply to ACC_LEVEL...  it usess focusout event ... so if u want that user fill the last value then make it all required... client side... with ClientOptions and clientValidation set to true

Comment: Maybe I to newbie to understanding javascript and yii. Any examples codes for try implement it?